# Why isn't this working to set the Java Applet always on top?

Tags: java, swing, always-on-top, jwindow

I am trying to set the window of my Java applet to be always on top so I am doing the following.

Is there a better way to set the window to be always on top?

The print statements that I put in to check give back true, but the window isn't actually always on top.

```
Window[] windows = Window.getWindows();
System.out.println(windows.length);
Window appletWindow = windows[0];
Window otherWindow = windows[1];
System.out.println(appletWindow.isAlwaysOnTopSupported());
System.out.println(otherWindow.isAlwaysOnTopSupported());
appletWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
otherWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
System.out.println(appletWindow.isAlwaysOnTop());
System.out.println(otherWindow.isAlwaysOnTop());
```

Comment: How could it b? It's embedded with in applet container, which, technically, you don't have control over

Comment: So it is not even possible to set it as always-on-top through an applet?